# How to fix the length for the string builder string in Winform C#?

Tags: c#, formatting, stringbuilder

In my project, I'm using a `StringBuilder` to create a table in `RichEditBox`. But in my column the data value is differ from each other. So it looks like shuffled data. But my excepted output is to be perfectly fix the length for the data in table. I can see the table as properly completed in my output .

Can anyone say how to fix the length to the string in `StringBuilder` in C#?

My code:

```
Connection();

try
{
    string Today = "Student Test Mark Details";
    string Line = "----------------------------------";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    cmd = new SqlCommand("select ExaminationName, ExaminationCenter, ExaminationDate, Subjects, MarkObtained, Total, Percentage, Grade from StudentMarksHistory where StudentCode='" + ICBEStudentCode.Text + "' and ExaminationName='" + TBExaminationName.Text + "' and ClassName='" + ICBEClassSection.Text + "' and Remark='Record Saved'", cs);

    StringBuilder paragraph = new StringBuilder();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                paragraph.Append(Today).Append("\t\n");
                paragraph.Append(Line).Append("\t\n\n\n\n\n");

                paragraph.Append("ExamName").Append("\t");
                paragraph.Append("ExamCenter").Append("\t");
                paragraph.Append("ExamDate").Append("\t");
                paragraph.Append("Subject").Append("\t\t\t");
                paragraph.Append("Mark").Append("\t");
                paragraph.Append("Total").Append("\t");
                paragraph.Append("Percentage").Append("\t");
                paragraph.Append("Grade").Append("\n\n");

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    DateTime DateName = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ExaminationDate"]);
                    string subject = dr["Subjects"].ToString().Trim();
                    //int Len = subject.Length;
                    //subject = subject.ToString().PadRight(50 - Len, ' ');
                    paragraph.Append(dr["ExaminationName"].ToString()).Append("\t");
                    paragraph.Append(dr["ExaminationCenter"].ToString()).Append("\t");
                    paragraph.Append(DateName.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")).Append("\t");
                    paragraph.Append(subject);
                    paragraph.Append(' ', 15 - subject.Length);
                    //paragraph.Append(subject.PadRight(100));
                    paragraph.Append(dr["MarkObtained"].ToString()).Append("\t");
                    paragraph.Append(dr["Total"].ToString()).Append("\t");
                    paragraph.Append(dr["Percentage"].ToString()).Append("\t");
                    paragraph.Append(dr["Grade"].ToString()).Append("\n");
                }
                string Notes = "************[ Minimum Pass Mark is 35 ]*************";
                paragraph.Append(" ").Append("\n\n\n\n");
                paragraph.Append(Notes).Append("\r\n");
                dr.Close();
                cs.Close();
            }
            RTBMessage.Text = paragraph.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Results expceted:

```
                                   Student Test Mark Details
                              ----------------------------------


ExamName        ExamCenter      ExamDate        Subject                 Mark    Total   

Class Test 1    Room No1        24/05/2013      STOREDPROCEDURE           97       404  
Class Test 1    Room No1        25/05/2013      DOTNET                   86       404     
Class Test 1    Room No1        26/05/2013      TAMIL                    80       404        
Class Test 1    Room No1        23/05/2013      SOCIAL                   80       404                                    
Class Test 1    Room No1        27/05/2013      COMPUTER                 61       404         



                          ************[ Minimum Pass Mark is 35 ]*************
```

Comment: If you're using Windows Forms, why are you trying to do everything in a RichEditBox? It looks like a data grid of some kind would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use TABs to align the column but use [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) through [AppendFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.appendformat.aspx) method of the StringBuilder

Just as an example for your first column.
I suppose that `ExamName` should be inserted left aligned in a column large 20 characters.
You could write

```
 paragraph.AppendFormat("{0:20}","ExamName");
```

while for the `Grade` column right aligned in a 6 char space

```
 paragraph.AppendFormat("{0:-6}\r\n", "Total");
```

Of course this kind of alignement is dependent on the kind of font used in the RichTextBox. If you use a proportional font there is no way to align this text in the way you like.

At the end I really suggest you to use a DataGridView instead

Answer (score 0):

As the lenght of your data is very fluctuating, do not add tabs "\t", this will not work if some data is longer than tabsize

You can use the

```
String.PadRight(Int32, Char)
```

Method if you know your maximum expected data lenght.

Remember the usage: the first parameter describes the total lengt not the number of characters to fill

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66f6d830(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I Don't No the Max Data Length so Wat Could I Do for this Now .